# How do I access the document ID in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am seemingly unable to access the resource.id value when trying queries using these rules. when I manually enter the schools id (the commented out line) the data returns fine. I only have 1 school and the doc ID definitely matches the string. but when I ask to match to the resource.id value, my rules return an 'insufficient permissions' error.

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
            //functions
        function signedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
            }
        
        function returnUID(){
        return request.auth.uid;
        }
  
  function getUserData() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/All%20Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
}
  
  
                match /All%20Users/{userID} {
          allow read,write: if 
          signedIn() && returnUID() == userID;
          }
  
          match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}{
            allow read, write: if
         //  signedIn() && getUserData().school == "f7asMxUvTs3uFhE08AJr"
             signedIn() && getUserData().school == resource.id
          }
          
          
    
  }
}
```

[image: Image of Data Hierarchy]

my structure is like this

All Schools / school (document) / Classrooms (subcollection)
All Users / User (document) (each user doc has a classroomID associated to it)

as a point of reference this is a query that is successful

`var docRef = db.collection("All Users").doc(uid).get()`

and the one that is failing

`db.collection("All Schools/" + properties.schoolid + "/Classrooms").onSnapshot()`

[update]
the working set of rules!

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
            //functions
        function signedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
            }
        
        function returnUID(){
        return request.auth.uid;
        }
  
  function getUserData() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/All%20Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
}
  
  
                match /All%20Users/{userID} {
          allow read,write: if 
          signedIn() && returnUID() == userID;
          }
  
          match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}{
            allow read, write: if   schoolID == 'f7asMxUvTs3uFhE08AJr'
           
          }
          match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}/Classrooms/{classId} {
  allow read, write: if getUserData().school == schoolID;
}
          match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}/Student%20List/{student} {
  allow read, write: if getUserData().school == schoolID;
}
    match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}/Staff/{staff} {
  allow read, write: if getUserData().school == schoolID;
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following rules will be effective on documents of 'All Schools' collection only and not documents of 'Classrooms' sub-collection:

```
match /All%20Schools/{schoolID} {
  // ...
}
```

That's why `db.collection("All Users").doc(uid).get()` works and fetching 'Classrooms' collection fail since you do not have any rules specified for it. Although you had a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) earlier (before editing the question), `resource` object contains data of those documents being matched in 'Classrooms' sub-collection and hence `getUserData().school == resource.id` failed too.

That being said, try specifying rules for 'Classrooms' sub-collection as well:

```
match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}/Classrooms/{classId} {
  allow read, write: if getUserData().school == schoolID;
}
```

Comment: This is it!! I thought that adding the wildcard to the top-level school would work. it didn't. instead I added permission for each subcollection in classroom. BAM!

Comment: @JaredGibb the recursive wildcard would work too but then you may have to use `get()` to read School document data which might incur an additional read.

Answer (score 1):

```
match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}/Classrooms/{classID} {
  // schoolID is the documentId
  allow read, write: if signedIn() && getUserData().school == schoolID
}
```

If this was my code, I would not use spaces in my collection or field names. Rather I will use `snake_case` or `camelCase`.

So instead of `All Schools`, I will use either `all_schools` or `allSchools`.

Comment: Thank you. i still get the error. I have double-checked that getUserData returns the correct value by looking at the doc in my browser. I am working though doing this in the cloud/shell emulator to see if I can get some debugging but that's new to me so may take time to get used to.

hindsight, i'd change this too and may end up having to. it's a pain in the but! but I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: Okay, give me a moment let me run this code with my simulator and see if I get any errors.

Comment: Access is allowed in my simulator. Wait, remember I change `schoolID=**` to `schoolID`. Did you also change that?

Comment: Peter, I missed that! I’m… indisposed for the next 8 minutes or so with family stuff but will publish this change and report my results! Thank you for your help here today, too!

Comment: So glad I could help. When you test it, if there are any problems, just let me know.

Comment: I updated to this `allow read, write: if signedIn() && getUserData().school == schoolID` and still getting the same error but not when i include the string that i copy/paste from the school field on the user document. 

i'll keep trying! still trying to figure out the emulator.     _______ as a side note. i am able to make a call that gets the user document no problem. in  my app I make a call to that first, then to a subcollection of the school. I'll add some structure above!

Comment: Previous value: `match /All%20Schools/{schoolID=**}{`, new value: `match /All%20Schools/{schoolID} {`. This is where I am referring to. If you use `schoolID=**`, it won't work.

Comment: Sorry. here is the full thing         `match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}{ allow read, write: if  signedIn() && getUserData().school == schoolID}`

Comment: Okay. Try this: `match /All%20Schools/{schoolID}{ allow read, write: if  'f7asMxUvTs3uFhE08AJr' == schoolID}`. If this works, it means the value of the schoolID is correct.

Comment: That did not work!  So, the value from the schoolID doesn’t match what I think it should. I grab the value from the only school. 

I only have 1 school in the collection. When I call the collection from my app without the rule, no issues occur. So I know I’m referencing the correct doc. 

If you see the screenshot above you can see the doc I’d does match what I’m entering in the string above and the value saved to the user. 

I’m lost at this point.

Comment: In `db.collection("All Schools/" + properties.schoolid + "/Classrooms").onSnapshot()`, you are fetching classrooms documents, so of course, my rules will not work. I assumed you wanted schools document. Let me update my answer.